# Why is pygame button not taking me to next function?

Tags: python, pygame

I am at the beginning of my first python project. I just figured out how to set true/false variables to make sure buttons don't overlap or are clickable on a page they aren't on. But I am now stuck on making a certain button go to a function. In my game I present the player with choices, and when they click on the choice it takes them to certain dialogue and then more choices. When I click on 'sit and wait' button (it's one of the first three choices), it takes me into a 'you decided to wait' type of dialogue. But after I click on the 'continue to wait' option, the button doesn't take me to the function which displays the text 'you decided to keep waiting' for some reason. I think I'm messing up the formatting of my if/else statements, but I'm not sure where. The same button also does not change color when cursor is hovering above it. The other buttons work fine. Any tips on either of these issues? Sorry for the long winded post, just want to be as clear as possible. Here is my code::::

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
win=pygame.display.set_mode((800,700))
win.fill((255,255,255))
our_game_display=pygame.Surface((800,700))
font_name = pygame.font.get_default_font()
class button():
    def __init__(self, color, x, y, width, height, text=''):
        self.color = color
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.text = text
    def draw(self, win, outline=None):
        # Call this method to draw the button on the screen
        if outline:
            pygame.draw.rect(win, outline, (self.x - 2, self.y - 2, self.width + 4, self.height + 4), 0)
        pygame.draw.rect(win, self.color, (self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height), 0)
        if self.text != '':
            font = pygame.font.SysFont('comicsans', 30)
            text = font.render(self.text, 1, (255, 255, 255))
            win.blit(text, (self.x + (self.width / 2 - text.get_width() / 2), self.y + (self.height / 2 - text.get_height() / 2)))
    def isOver(self, pos):
        # Pos is the mouse position or a tuple of (x,y) coordinates
        if pos[0] > self.x and pos[0] < self.x + self.width:
            if pos[1] > self.y and pos[1] < self.y + self.height:
                return True
        return False
def draw_text(text, size, x, y):
        pygame.font.init()
        font = pygame.font.Font(font_name, size)
        text_surface = font.render(text, True, (255,255,255))
        text_rect = text_surface.get_rect()
        text_rect.center = (x, y)
        our_game_display.blit(text_surface, text_rect)
def keep_waiting():
    our_game_display.fill((0,0,0))
    draw_text('You continue to sit and wait. Will anything happen?', 20, 800 / 2, 700 / 2 - 100)
    win.blit(our_game_display,(0,0))
    pygame.display.update()
def yell_choice():
    our_game_display.fill((0, 0, 0))
    draw_text('You yell to see if anyone can hear you.', 20, 800 / 2, 700 / 2 - 100)
    win.blit(our_game_display, (0, 0))
    pygame.display.update()
def sit_choice():
    our_game_display.fill((0,0,0))
    draw_text('So you decided to sit and wait...nothing happens. What now?', 20, 800 / 2, 700 / 2 - 100)
    win.blit(our_game_display,(0,0))
    KeepWaitingButton.draw(win,(255,255,255))
    pygame.display.update()
def search_choice():
    our_game_display.fill((0,0,0))
    draw_text('So you decided to search', 20, 800 / 2, 700 / 2 - 100)
    win.blit(our_game_display,(0,0))
    pygame.display.update()
def beginning_question():
    our_game_display.fill((0, 0, 0))
    draw_text('The story of this game depends on your choices. Do you wish to play?', 20, 800 / 2, 700 / 2 - 100)
    win.blit(our_game_display, (0, 0))
    PlayButton.draw(win, (255, 255, 255))
    pygame.display.update()
def begin_game():
    our_game_display.fill((0,0,0))
    draw_text("You wake up, or...at least you think you do. Even though your eyes are open,", 20, 800 / 2, 700 / 2 - 300)
    draw_text("they still can't detect anything in the complete darkness that surrounds you.", 20, 800 / 2, 700 / 2 - 270)
    draw_text("What do you do?", 20, 800 / 2, 700 / 2 - 210)
    win.blit(our_game_display,(0,0))
    SitWaitButton.draw(win,(255,255,255))
    SearchButton.draw(win,(255,255,255))
    YellHelpButton.draw(win,(255,255,255))
    pygame.display.update()
#game loop
#color,x,y,width,height
PlayButton=button((0,0,0),283,700/2,250,100,"Let's play.")
SitWaitButton=button((0,0,0),500,500,200,50,'Sit and wait..')
SearchButton=button((0,0,0),250,600,600,50,'Get up and try to search your surroundings.')
YellHelpButton=button((0,0,0),250,400,600,50,'Yell to see if anyone is there.')
KeepWaitingButton=button((0,0,0),500,500,200,50,'Keep waiting...')
game_begun='Input' #beginning choice variable
search_option='Input'#search variable
sit_option='Input' #sitting variable
yell_option = 'Input' #yelling variable
keep_waiting_option = 'Input'
menu = True
lock_1=True
keep_waiting_lock=True
while True:
    if search_option=='Go':
        search_choice()
    elif yell_option=='Go':
        yell_choice()
    elif sit_option=='Go':
        sit_choice()
    elif keep_waiting_option=='Go':
        keep_waiting()
    elif game_begun=='Go':
        begin_game()
    else:
        beginning_question()
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        pos=pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
            pygame.quit()
            quit()
    #yes and no buttons for beginning question
        if event.type==pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:  #menu if/else
            if PlayButton.isOver(pos) and menu==True:
                menu=False
                game_begun='Go'
            elif YellHelpButton.isOver(pos) and menu==False and lock_1==True:
                lock_1=False
                yell_option = 'Go'
                print("this button is working")
            elif SitWaitButton.isOver(pos) and menu==False and lock_1==True:
                keep_waiting_lock=False
                lock_1=False
                sit_option = 'Go'
                print("this button is working")
            elif SearchButton.isOver(pos) and menu==False and lock_1==True:
                lock_1=False
                search_option = 'Go'
                print("this button is working")
            elif KeepWaitingButton.isOver(pos) and keep_waiting_lock==False:
                keep_waiting_option='Go'
                print("this button is working")
        if event.type==pygame.MOUSEMOTION:  #first option buttons
            if PlayButton.isOver(pos) and menu==True:
                PlayButton.color = (0, 0, 139)
            elif YellHelpButton.isOver(pos):
                YellHelpButton.color = (0, 0, 139)
            elif SitWaitButton.isOver(pos):
                SitWaitButton.color = (0, 0, 139)
            elif SearchButton.isOver(pos):
                SearchButton.color = (0, 0, 139)
            elif KeepWaitingButton.isOver(pos):
                KeepWaitingButton.color = (0, 0, 139)
            else:
                PlayButton.color = (0, 0, 0)
                YellHelpButton.color = (0, 0, 0)
                SitWaitButton.color = (0, 0, 0)
                SearchButton.color = (0, 0, 0)
                KeepWaitingButton.color = (0, 0, 0)
```

Comment: What does "go to a function" or "take to a function" mean? I think you have a fundamental misunderstanding about how functions work. They are not "targets"; they are chunks of code that you can execute that will *return a value* that is fed *back to the place where they were called*. You should first make sure that you can write a game with similarly complex logic, using the command line instead of Pygame. It is important to practice the fundamentals and have a clear understanding of programming logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Decent start.  Just put commonly used values in variables, such as origin & colors, so you have a better description of what's going on.  Helps avoid [magic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_%28programming%29).  Don't have to be religious about it, like padding for text outline, you already know what that is just by looking at it.

Could skip sending width & height values to your buttons, if they're dynamically generated around size of text.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3
##  pip3 install pygame
##  python3 -m pip install pygame

import pygame
pygame .init()
pygame .font .init()  ##  don't need to initialize font every turn, just do it once

screensize = Width, Height = 800, 700
halfwidth, halfheight = Width /2, Height /2
win = pygame .display .set_mode( screensize )
our_game_display = pygame .Surface( screensize )

font_name = pygame .font .get_default_font()
sansfont = pygame .font .SysFont( 'comicsans',  30 )
fontsize = 20

origin = 0, 0  ##  use variables for commonly used values
black = 0, 0, 0
blue = 0,  0,  139
white = 255, 255, 255

class button():
    def __init__( self,  color,  x,  y,  text ):
        self .color = color
        self .x = x
        self .y = y
        self .width = 20
        self .height = 10
        self .text = text

    def draw( self,  win,  outline = None ):
        ##  Call this method to draw button on screen
        if self .text != '':
            text = sansfont .render( self .text,  1,  white )
            self .width = text .get_width()
            self .height = text .get_height()

        if outline:
            pygame .draw .rect( win,  outline,  ( self .x -12,  self .y -12,  self .width +24,  self .height +24 ),  0 )

        pygame .draw .rect( win,  self .color,  ( self .x -10,  self .y -10,  self .width +20,  self .height +20 ),  0 )

        if self .text != '':
            win .blit( text,  ( self .x, self .y ) )

    def isOver( self,  pos ):
        ##  mouse position or a tuple of ( x,  y ) coordinates
        return pos[0] > self .x -13 and pos[0] < self .x -13 +self .width +26 \
        and pos[1] > self .y -13 and pos[1] < self .y -13 +self .height +26


def draw_text( text,  size,  x,  y ):
        font = pygame .font .Font( font_name,  size )
        text_surface = font .render( text,  True,  white )
        text_rect = text_surface .get_rect()
        text_rect .center = ( x,  y )
        our_game_display .blit( text_surface,  text_rect )


def keep_waiting():
    our_game_display .fill( black )
    draw_text( 'You continue to sit and wait.  Will anything happen?',  20,  halfwidth,  halfheight -100 )
    win .blit( our_game_display,  origin )
    pygame .display .update()


def yell_choice():
    our_game_display .fill( black )
    draw_text( 'You yell to see if anyone can hear you.',  20,  halfwidth,  halfheight -100 )
    win .blit( our_game_display,  origin )
    pygame .display .update()


def sit_choice():
    our_game_display .fill( black )
    draw_text( 'So you decided to sit and wait... nothing happens.  What now?',  20,  halfwidth,  halfheight -100 )
    win .blit( our_game_display,  origin )
    WaitButton .draw( win,  white )
    pygame .display .update()


def search_choice():
    our_game_display .fill( black )
    draw_text( 'So you decided to search.',  20,  halfwidth,  halfheight -100 )
    win .blit( our_game_display,  origin )
    pygame .display .update()


def beginning_question():
    our_game_display .fill( black )
    draw_text( 'The story of this game depends on your choices.  Do you wish to play?',  20,  halfwidth,  halfheight -100 )
    win .blit( our_game_display,  origin )
    PlayButton .draw( win,  white )
    pygame .display .update()


def begin_game():
    our_game_display .fill( black )
    draw_text( "You wake up,  or...  at least you think you do.  Even though your eyes are open,",  fontsize,  halfwidth,  halfheight -300 )
    draw_text( "they still can't detect anything in the complete darkness that surrounds you.",  fontsize,  halfwidth,  halfheight -270 )
    draw_text( "What do you do?",  fontsize,  halfwidth,  halfheight -210 )
    win .blit( our_game_display,  origin )
    SitWaitButton .draw( win,  white )
    SearchButton .draw( win,  white )
    YellHelpButton .draw( win,  white )
    pygame .display .update()


##  game loop  ..  color,  x,  y,  msg
PlayButton = button( black,  halfwidth -100,  halfheight,  "Let's play." )
SitWaitButton = button( black,  halfwidth -100,  halfheight +50,  'Sit and wait..' )
SearchButton = button( black,  halfwidth -100,  halfheight +100,  'Get up and try to search your surroundings.' )
YellHelpButton = button( black,  halfwidth -100,  halfheight +150,  'Yell to see if anyone is there.' )
WaitButton = button( black,  halfwidth -100,  halfheight +200,  'Keep waiting...' )

game_begun = 'Input'  ##  beginning choice
search_option = 'Input'
sit_option = 'Input' 
yell_option = 'Input'
wait_option = 'Input'

menu = True
lock_1 = True
wait_lock = True

while True:
    if search_option == 'Go':   search_choice()
    elif wait_option == 'Go':   keep_waiting()
    elif yell_option == 'Go':   yell_choice()
    elif sit_option == 'Go':    sit_choice()
    elif game_begun == 'Go':   begin_game()
    else:             beginning_question()

    for event in pygame .event .get():
        pos = pygame .mouse .get_pos()
        if event .type == pygame .QUIT:
            running = False
            pygame .quit()
            quit()

        ##  yes & no buttons for beginning question
        if event .type == pygame .MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:  ##  menu if/else
            if PlayButton .isOver( pos ) and menu == True:
                menu = False
                game_begun = 'Go'

            elif YellHelpButton .isOver( pos ) and menu == False and lock_1 == True:
                lock_1 = False
                yell_option = 'Go'
                print( "YellHelp button is working" )

            elif SitWaitButton .isOver( pos ) and menu == False and lock_1 == True:
                wait_lock = False
                lock_1 = False
                sit_option = 'Go'
                print( "SitWait button is working" )

            elif SearchButton .isOver( pos ) and menu == False and lock_1 == True:
                lock_1 = False
                search_option = 'Go'
                print( "Search button is working" )

            elif WaitButton .isOver( pos ) and wait_lock == False:
                wait_option = 'Go'
                print( "Wait button is working" )

        if event .type == pygame .MOUSEMOTION:  ##  first option buttons
            PlayButton .color = black
            YellHelpButton .color = black
            SitWaitButton .color = black
            SearchButton .color = black
            WaitButton .color = black

            if PlayButton .isOver( pos ) and menu == True:
                PlayButton .color = blue

            elif YellHelpButton .isOver( pos ):
                YellHelpButton .color = blue

            elif SitWaitButton .isOver( pos ):
                SitWaitButton .color = blue

            elif SearchButton .isOver( pos ):
                SearchButton .color = blue

            elif WaitButton .isOver( pos ):
                WaitButton .color = blue
```

Comment: Thanks!!! And thank you for helping me clean up my code. it looks much better :)

Answer (score 1):

Can you double check keep_waiting_lock when "Keep Waiting" is selected? It looks like keep_waiting will only be called if sit_choice is called first due to keep_waiting_lock being initialized to true.